# ARKit 2.0 – How to stop Audio from playing in SCNView?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, arscnview

I am developing an AR application which is needed to play an audio.

I have done that like:

```
guard let audioSource = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "sample.mp3") else { return }
audioSource.loops = false
audioSource.load()
node.runAction(SCNAction.playAudio(audioSource, waitForCompletion: false))
```

It works fine except that I can't stop it from playing.

I have also tried:

```
node.enumerateChildNodes { (childNode, _) in
   childNode.removeAllAudioPlayers()
   childNode.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

But it is still playing.

Does anybody have any idea of how to stop it?

**Update:** 
I have already tried:

```
guard let audioSource = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "sample.mp3") else {return}
audioSource.load()
player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource)
node.addAudioPlayer(player)
```

and remove it like what @Andy said:

```
node.enumerateChildNodes { (childNode, _) in
   childNode.removeAudioPlayer(player)
   childNode.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

but it is still not working.

P.S. I'm using iOS 12 beta 9, xCode 10 beta 4 and macOS Mojave 10.14

**Solution:** the problem wasn't the ARAudio, the reason was: the SCNAudioPlayer was added to the node directly and I was trying to remove it from child node.

Answer (score 1):

To stop audio playback use a `removeAudioPlayer(_:)` instance method. [Look here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1522767-removeaudioplayer).

```
func removeAudioPlayer(_ player: SCNAudioPlayer)
```

> This method removes the specified audio player from the node, stopping playback.

*You can also remove all audio players:*

```
func removeAllAudioPlayers()
```

To add audio player use the following instance method:

```
func addAudioPlayer(_ player: SCNAudioPlayer)
```

This method adds the specified auto player to the node and begins playback.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I've already tried that, but still not working.

Comment: Are you using iOS 12? If so, try it in iOS 11.

Comment: Yes, I'm on iOS 12. because it's ARKit 2 (I'm using object detection), it's not working on iOS 11 I guess.

Comment: Just try with ARKit 1.5 in iOS 11. To be sure it's working... If audio is not working in iOS 11, there's a problem with you code, if it's working, there's a problem with iOS 12 beta )))).

Comment: well, such a mistake, as you can see I added the audioPlayer directly to the node so I had to remove it from the node not from the childNodes of the node.